# Rails: Extract hour from datetime_select in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a form which uses a datetime_select form helper, as follows:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_date %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :start_date %>
</div>
```

I'd like to be able to parse that date for the individual fields that make up that DateTime in my model, but I can't seem to extract valid data using the following code:

```
# This code is in the model, so there's no params hash
hour = self["start_date(4i)"].to_i
```

I'm using a `before_create` callback to call the method containing the relevant code and it keeps coming up as '0' without regard to the actual setting on the hour option select in that view. The extracted hour will be saved to a column of type integer.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Is `start_date` a column in your table?

Comment: start_date is indeed a column in the table.

Comment: did you try `hour = self.start_date.hour`?

Comment: @H-man Embarassingly obvious... sometimes it's hard to see the forest for the trees. Turn that comment into an answer and reap your +15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `hour = self.start_date.hour`?